# Cannot get LogCat to work

Tags: android

I'm trying to use `logCat`.
I have the following code that gets executed

```
 Log.i("MyLog", "Test to see if it works");
```

But the Logcat on eclipse only shows
All messages (no filters)

Is there a setting or something in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Logcat menu there is a Green plus above the `All messages (no filters)`

Either use `"MyLog"` at the `Log Tag` input-field to only see your log that is tagged with `"MyLog"`,

or use your applications namespace (like `com.example.your_app`) at the `by Application Name` to show all logs of your application without the spam you got with all messages of Eclipse and the Emulator. (This does still include the `dalvikvm` that increases the heap size, `Choreographer` which warns you when you do too much work on the Main Thread, and similar app-related logs though.)

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter (the green plus) with **`by Log Tag:`**`MyLog` and **`by Log Level:`**`info`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a filter manually with that tag from the Log.i in the LogCat view. You can use the + icon next to the Saved filters label